# Describe layouts REST call

Tags: rest-api, page-layout, rest-service

I am trying to use newly exposed endpoint in API v.28 i.e. /describe/layouts

Out of the various possible REST resources mentioned for describing layout, I can only use this one

For a layout description for a specific object, use `/vXX.X/sobjects/Object/describe/layouts/` 
This call only returns a single default layout for the object.

All other REST resources like

- Descriptions of global layouts: `/vXX.X/sobjects/Global/describe/layouts/`
- Describe a single layout: `v28.0/sobjects/global/describe/layouts/ContactLayout`

I am getting

```
[{"message":"The requested resource does not exist","errorCode":"NOT_FOUND"}]
```

My requirement is to fetch all layouts for an object, or get layout for an object by name.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The `/vXX.X/sobjects/Global/describe/layouts/` call doesn't return the collection of layouts for all SObjects, but rather the layouts for the 'global publisher'. This call only works if you have **Setup | App Setup | Chatter | Settings | Enable Publisher Actions** checked, in which case, you will receive a response along the lines of

```
{
  "id" : "00hE0000000QO6qIAG",
  "relatedLists" : [ ],
  "quickActionList" : {
    "quickActionListItems" : [ {
      "type" : "Post",
      "label" : "Post",
      "iconUrl" : null,
      "quickActionName" : "FeedItem.TextPost",
      "miniIconUrl" : null,
      "targetSobjectType" : null
    }, {
      "type" : "Post",
      "label" : "File",
      "iconUrl" : null,
      "quickActionName" : "FeedItem.ContentPost",
      "miniIconUrl" : null,
      "targetSobjectType" : null
    }, {
      "type" : "Post",
      "label" : "Link",
      "iconUrl" : null,
      "quickActionName" : "FeedItem.LinkPost",
      "miniIconUrl" : null,
      "targetSobjectType" : null
    }, {
      "type" : "Post",
      "label" : "Poll",
      "iconUrl" : null,
      "quickActionName" : "FeedItem.PollPost",
      "miniIconUrl" : null,
      "targetSobjectType" : null
    } ]
  },
  "buttonLayoutSection" : null,
  "detailLayoutSections" : [ ],
  "editLayoutSections" : [ ],
  "multirowEditLayoutSections" : [ ],
  "offlineLinks" : [ ]
}
```

I'm investigating how to obtain all the layouts for a given SObject - I'll update here when I discover the answer.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot Pat for sharing this finding, I will wait for the second update !